# MongoDB with millions of rows

Tags: mongodb

I've got a MongoDB with 52M documents in it.  I can't get any queries to ever finish.  There are no proper indexes, so I think that might be why. However, when I try to build the index it seemed like that failed as well. I left it for 2 hours and the database was still locked when I came back. I had to restart the service.

Any ideas or things to look for? I thought with Mongo I should be able to query on millions of rows.

Sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54dfbcfe8b0de0cd148b4567"),
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "articles" : [ 
        {
            "sequenceId" : "423671544757",
            "id" : "20450468768",
            "language" : "Danish",
            "title" : "Se det spøjse billede: Bendtner og co. tvunget i midtergangen",
            "content" : "De er millionærer med dyre biler og sikkert også råd til en flybillet ved nødudgangen, men da Wolfsburg-spillerne skulle transporteres til lørdagens kamp mod Leverkusen skete det med tog til Köln. \n \nDet blev ikke en helt almindelig tur for Nicklas Bendtner og holdkammeraterne, for den togvogn, som Wolfsburg havde bestilt sine pladsbilletter til, kom aldrig frem. I stedet for vogn 858 kom vogn 848, og så var der ingen reserverede pladser til de dyre fodboldben. \n \nDerfor måtte blandt andre en af holdets største stjerner Kevin De Bruyne sætte sig i mellemgangen i toget, som du kan se på billedet her fra den noget alternative tur for Wolfsburg-holdet. \n \nDen anderledes togtur kom dog ikke til at få den store betydning for Wolfsburg, for der var masser af mål i holdet, da de slog Leverkusen 5-4 lørdag.",
            "tags" : [],
            "publishedDate" : "2015-02-14T21:17:00Z",
            "harvestDate" : "2015-02-14T21:22:45Z",
            "url" : "http://ct.moreover.com/?a=20450468768&p=20x&v=1&x=PMgZEU9pWnWzzrJkGesHeA",
            "outboundUrls" : [],
            "dataFormat" : "text",
            "loginStatus" : "",
            "duplicateGroupId" : "20450468768",
            "media" : {
                "audio" : [],
                "images" : [ 
                    {
                        "url" : "http://b.bimg.dk/node-images/301/8/140x80/8301685-fbl-ger-bundesliga-leverkusen-wolfsburg.jpg"
                    }
                ],
                "video" : []
            },
            "publishingPlatform" : [],
            "adultLanguage" : "false",
            "topics" : [],
            "companies" : [],
            "locations" : [],
            "semantics" : {
                "events" : [],
                "entities" : []
            },
            "author" : {
                "name" : "Michel Wikkelsø Davidsen",
                "publishingPlatform" : []
            },
            "licenses" : [],
            "source" : {
                "name" : "B.T. online",
                "homeUrl" : "http://www.bt.dk",
                "publisher" : "",
                "category" : "Trade",
                "editorialRank" : "3",
                "location" : {
                    "country" : "Denmark",
                    "countryCode" : "DK",
                    "region" : "Europe",
                    "subregion" : "Northern Europe",
                    "state" : "",
                    "zipArea" : "",
                    "zipCode" : ""
                },
                "feed" : {
                    "id" : "169662017",
                    "name" : "B.T. online",
                    "mediaType" : "News",
                    "tags" : [],
                    "language" : "Unassigned",
                    "dataFormat" : "text",
                    "rank" : {
                        "inboundLinkCount" : "8901"
                    },
                    "inWhiteList" : "true",
                    "autoTopics" : [],
                    "editorialTopics" : [ 
                        "Miscellaneous"
                    ],
                    "genre" : "General"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexing can take long time, specially if your server does not have enough computing power. Slow / inadequate disk, inadequate RAM, CPU can all slow down index creation. Even if you are running on a better server, fields that you choose to index, can cause long runtime.

I would avoid multi key indexes and try running indexing in the background. Since you have not provided a sample document, I cannot get into specifics.